Issue to build angular app after upgrading of angular version 12 to 13
i have successfully upgraded the angular version 12 to 13 but while building with the command "ng build --configuration production --aot --build-optimizer --common-chunk --delete-output-path --progress --vendor-chunk"
got an error  Error screenshot 
Below are package.json and tsconfig.json
package.json Package.json
tsconfig.json tsconfig.json

I think this related github issue will help you resolve it.
Could you try updating the package @angular-builders/custom-webpack so that it has the latest version of typescript, which might fix the issue.
Also please find below a blank stackblitz project, where you can check with this tsconfig.json and package.json.
Blank Stackblitz
